# Hadoop command not found in bootstrap actions

Tags: hadoop, emr, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster which uses, as a bootstrap action, a `script.sh` from my s3. In this, it includes some `hadoop dfs -distcp` and `hadoop dfs -copyToLocal` commands. If I log in to a built EMR cluster and run the commands, its absolutely fine, but if I try to do it as part of the bootstrap actions it fails. Log file here:

```
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
/mnt/var/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/setup.sh: line 4: hadoop: command not found
/mnt/var/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/setup.sh: line 7: hdfs: command not found
/mnt/var/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/setup.sh: line 8: hadoop: command not found`
```

I assume it means that the `hadoop` executables havent been loaded yet, but if so, how can I delay? The chain of actions I'm trying to do is start EMR cluster, automatically get data from s3, perform an analysis, generate output, copy output back to s3, shutdown cluster

Thanks!

Comment: What applications are you running under Hadoop? eg Hive, Impala, Presto? These systems know how to talk to S3 directly, so we provide suggestions if you tell us what you are using.

Comment: Hi. This is a fair point. I guess the better thing to do is explain in a more direct way what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to use the `bootstrap actions` in EMR to automatically get some data, process it, and shut down the cluster. How I was trying to do this was through `hadoop` command calls from the CLI. In the first step this was Python & Scikit learn using data from S3, but I'd like to expand to Spark & Hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While traditional Hadoop clusters store data in **HDFS** (Hadoop Distributed File System), it is recommended that Amazon EMR clusters store their source data and final output in **Amazon S3**.

Using Amazon S3 for storage offers **several benefits**:

- Unlimited storage (whereas HDFS is a fixed size in a cluster)
- Persistent data storage (whereas data in HDFS is lost when an Amazon EMR cluster is terminated)
- Easier integration with other systems that know how to read/write to Amazon S3

Rather than loading data from Amazon S3 via **bootstrap actions**, many Hadoop services can natively interact with Amazon S3. For example, here is a **Hive** command that creates a table based upon data already stored in Amazon S3:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE orders_s3_export 
( order_id string, customer_id string, order_date int, total double ) 
PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LOCATION 's3://us-west-2-aws-training/awsu-ilt/big-data/v2.0/data/lab1/data/ddb-orders';
```

When a `SELECT` command is run on this table, Hive will automatically look in Amazon S3 for the data files. Similarly, when data is inserted into the table, it will be stored within files on Amazon S3 (which is good for the final output of a Hive job).

See: [Additional Features of Hive in Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hive-additional-features.html)

Spark is also able to access data directly from Amazon S3.

See: [Reading and Writing S3 Data with Apache Spark](http://www.sparktutorials.net/reading-and-writing-s3-data-with-apache-spark)

Comment: So in my example above where I want to process some data and auto-terminate a cluster, I would use a `custom step` to create the Hive table (for example) and then another `custom step` to run a Spark job over it?

Comment: Yes, but rather than using a **custom step**, EMR specifically understands steps for some apps such as **Hive**. See: [Add Steps Using the CLI and Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/add-steps-cli-console.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, hadoop executables haven't been loaded yet at the time the bootstrap action is executed.

As described here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/bootstrap-step-emr/ bootstrap actions are the first thing to run after an Amazon EMR cluster has been provisioned and transitions from the STARTING cluster state to the BOOTSTRAPPING cluster state.

To be able to perform your commands you need to use a step instead.